# iCal4j Principles not found

Tags: groovy, caldav, ical4j

We are trying to connect to our instance of the CalendarStore but we don't understand the exception, that we get back when executing the code.
The Error we're having:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.ObjectStoreException: net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.FailedOperationException: Principals not found
```

We also know that the error occurs in line 62. Please note that I have edited the strings in the variables to not expose them to the public.

```
import com.github.caldav4j.CalDAVCollection;

import com.github.caldav4j.CalDAVConstants;
import com.github.caldav4j.exceptions.CalDAV4JException;
import com.github.caldav4j.methods.CalDAV4JMethodFactory;
import com.github.caldav4j.methods.HttpGetMethod;
import com.github.caldav4j.model.request.CalendarQuery;
import com.github.caldav4j.util.GenerateQuery;

import net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.ObjectStoreException;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.dav.CalDavCalendarCollection;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.dav.CalDavCalendarStore;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.dav.PathResolver;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute;
import org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoutePlanner;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultSchemePortResolver;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Component;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ComponentList;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.VEvent;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.data.ParserException;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.connector.CalendarStore;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


String USER = "User";
String PASS = "dont matter";


g_log.info("Start");

String uri = "our uri";

String prodId = "hm";
URL url = new URL("Our url");
PathResolver pathResolver = PathResolver.CHANDLER;

CalendarStore<CalDavCalendarCollection> calendarStore = new CalDavCalendarStore(prodId, url, pathResolver);

boolean testCon = calendarStore.connect(USER.toString(), PASS.toCharArray());

g_log.info("testCon: "+ testCon);
```